# Pointer to pointer is causing crash

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, crash

Sample Code

```
sf::Drawable *mDrawables = new  sf::Shape(sf::Shape::Circle(-10, -10,5,sf::Color::Green));
Particle particle(mDrawables);


Particle::Particle(sf::Drawable *hum)
{
    *mDrawables = *hum;
}
```

From the narrowing down I have done, I figure the crash is happening somewhere in here. Once the constructor is called, the program crashes. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post a **complete** code. This isn’t informative, other than to say that you certainly don’t *want* those semantics.

Comment: is mDrawables a member of Particle? Looks now it is...

Comment: The `mDrawables` inside of the `Particle` constructor...is that a member variable? Or is that the global scope variable from the first line?

Comment: mDrawables is a member of Particle, the post below answered my question. I was dereferencing when I should not have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see pointer to pointer?

```
*mDrawables = *hum;
```

mDrawables is a pointer, but *mDrawables dereferenced pointer and may be class is not copyable.

May be you should try this

```
mDrawables = hum;
```

Also i hope what `sf::Shape` inherited from `sf::Drawable`

Comment: This did it. I knew that sf::Shape inherited from sf::Drawable, but I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong lol. Thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're over-writing the contents of `mDrawables` with the contents of `mDrawables` (aliased as the parameter `hum` in the `Particle` constructor).

The line `*mDrawables = *hum` should be read as "assign the contents of `hum` to the contents of `mDrawables`".

It's hard to tell why this might cause a crash; there's not enough details in the code sample (I don't know what a `Shape` does when you copy it).

I think you might need to re-structure the design here, but I can't tell what your overall intent is, so I can't give you any good advice in that regard.